# Can't install visual studio 2013 on windows 7

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded the ISO file of Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on the Microsoft MSDN website. I could install it on my home PC running Windows 8.1 without problems. However when I try to install it on my office PC running Windows 7 SP1, I get an error message. I even tried to install the "web installer" version, I always get the following error message:

[image]

Comment: can you check the eventlog? the application log should contain a more detailed error message.

Comment: The error code is for the ArgumentNullException, hopefully the detailed information contains a clue to what is null.

Answer (score 3):

In our case installing Sp1 for Windows 7 helped.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem (and it was killing me!). I solved it going to Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Turn off windows features, then I Disabled Microsoft Framework 3.5 and then It worked! Of course, when you finished the installation, you should turn it on as it was before.
Hope this helps!
Bst Regards!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to double check and ensure your video driver(s) are up to date, as there have been reports of the installer and the IDE crashing on startup, that are due to issues related to WPF's use of hardware acceleration.

I've seen a few issues resolved by disabling hardware acceleration via the registry key mentioned in the MSDN forum post : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ee8e5918-877f-4399-9658-64e817d6ea1b/visual-studio-2013-crashes-on-setup?forum=vssetup.

Sincerely,

Comment: I had this problem. I disabled my display adapter and then it installed successfully. Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10 via VirtualBox VM using Guest Additions.

Answer (score 1):

Having same problem.  From the command line run the installer with /Full /Q.  This will install it without the UI.  A less than optimal solution if you want to change the default locations, but sometimes you just have to get it done.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to go through the installer with UI is to disable any hardware acceleration (and reenable it afterwards)

(windows 7) Go to Display, Screen Resolution, Advanced Settings, TroubleShoot, Change Settings 
Set the slider for Hardware Acceleration to none, and accept.

The visual studio setup ui should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was the stupid AMD 'Raptr' utility that installs with the AMD driver. Literally having this running was crashing the Visual studio installer:

From the Application Log viewer:

> Faulting application name: 
>   en_visual_studio_professional_2013_with_update_5_x86_web_install, version: 
>   12.0.40629.0, time stamp: 0x544ac542
>   Faulting module name: ltc_game32-103398.dll, version: 1.0.0.1, time stamp: 
>   0x560b0dcc
>   Exception code: 0xc0000417
>   Fault offset: 0x000aa069
>   Faulting process id: 0x2334
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d1089e82a903a4
>   Faulting application path: 
>   c:\Users[myusername]\Downloads\en_visual_studio_professional_2013_with_update_5_x86_web_installer_6815765.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\PROGRA~2\Raptr\ltc_game32-103398.dll
>   Report Id: 6977618d-4f5f-40a2-b3a7-f34876626ea7
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

Seems utterly ridiculous, but as soon as I shut Raptr down, the installer worked fine.

Nothing like 2 days of fighting with the installer to figure this out.

Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues installing VS2013 the log referred to framework 4.5 problems.
I attempted to fix this a number of times and then gave up.

I then went to Microsoft website 4.5.1 framework download and now its installed.

Hope that helps

Geoff

Answer (score 0):

The web installer keeps crashing for me. The event log reported that the crash occurred in my graphics drivers (Intel HD Graphics). I am unable to update my graphics drivers, so that forced me to seek other means.

What solved it for me, was downloading the full ISO file for Visual Studio 2013, and installing using that. It seems it is either a separate build, or it doesn't touch the same execution-paths as the web installer.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was faulting ltc_game32-96675.dll which is from the AMD Raptor overlay. Unloading that allowed me to install without crashing.