# Unable to Install VS 2013 on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to install VS 2013  on Windows Server 2008 R2. Running the vs_professional.exe gave me a pop-up saying "The specified program requires a newer version of Windows".

Any help on this please?

Comment: "vs_professional.exe"? Is that what the real Visual Studio installer is called?

Comment: Yes. The Name of the installer file is vs_professional.exe

Comment: And that came in the Visual Studio ISO?

Comment: Hmm... strange; Visual Studio 2013 can definitely be installed on Windows server 2008R2. Is the server up to date service-pack wise? Does it have .NET 4.5 installed? [Check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815713/cant-install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: (For the record; Windows 7 and Server 2008R2 come from the same kernel, so the info there may be relevant.)

Comment: You need to have Service Pack 1 installed according to the [system requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements).

Comment: Yes. Its up to date. It has .Net 4.5 installed. As suggeseted in the link am now intalling 4.5.1. Will check if that resolves the issue.

Comment: It has Service Pack 2 Installed.

Comment: Also, its a 32-bit server. In the System Requirments they have mentioned as(x64). Is that stopping the installation?.

Comment: @AndrewBarber : No good even after installing .Net 4.5.1. I guess this because of server being a 32 bit Operating System–

Comment: Ahhh, unfortunately, I think that's it. According to the [System Requirements page](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-professional-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements), only 64bit 2008R2 works :(

Comment: @SenthilArasu there is no `Windows Server 2008 R2 32 bit`, 2008 R2 is only 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it resulted to be i was running the installer from `Total Commander Ultima Prime`, once i executed from the `windows explorer` the error disappeared and i was able of installing the `Visual Studio`.